# Ruby on Rails and WebSphere Can I have both and either?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websphere

I read where you can have Ruby on Rails running in WebSphere and I think I might try it.  If I make the website in RoR in WebSphere but later want to run just ruby on rails with with Apache, can I do that?  I want websphere because I'll want it for other things but I have another problem where the same website will suffice but cannot take the overhead of websphere (but can ror).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can write the pure rails app first and run it on JRuby, then convert it to WAR, install activerecord-jdbc-adapter and deploy on Websphere. Here is a nice guide: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0801_shillington/0801_shillington.html

When you are done with websphere just redeploy the app as pure rails on apache or even better on mod_passenger (and switch to normal db adapter)

Comment: This guides seems outdated. Have you actually got this to work?